Is a thing just a class with only one member?
Imagine this ontology:
Thing > Language > European Language > Nordic Language > Scandinavian Language

Each of the above are a type of thing, which seems to imply that there can be one or more instances of such a thing.
An instance of a Scandinavian language could be Norwegian.
On the one hand, you can consider an instance of a type to be an orthogonal type of relation to merely being a subtype. So you would say that Norwegian is an instance of a Scandinavian language, not a subtype.
Each of the above classes can have associated properties. An instance of a class instantiates values for its properties. So maybe Norwegian is defined by those choices of values for the properties of a Scandinavian language. If a language has a lexicon and a grammar, then Norwegian must have a lexicon (the set of words in Norwegian) and a grammar (the set of grammar rules of Norwegian).
Because Norwegian is defined by certain properties, what if we created a type, Norwegian, and specified that it must have properties like a Norwegian lexicon, and a Norwegian grammar (both of which are also classes). We could say that a Norwegian lexicon is any lexicon which has the following words: [list the words of Norwegian].
Now it appears that Norwegian is a type of thing defined by certain properties and relationships, and it just happens to have only one instance (the language Norwegian).
It seems like any instance can be converted into a class with only one member.
This might also seem more accurate if we consider contexts in which things commonly taken to be unique no longer are. If there are parallel universes, there can be another person with the exact same properties as me, but we are not the same instance. We are both “a Julius”, an instantiation of type “Julius”, with my exact characteristics and personal history.
Does this imply that we don’t need the concept of an “instance”? Can everything be defined as a collection of properties or relationships?

It reminds me a bit of:

a Borges story about a secret society of “idealists” who only believe in the reality of mental representations
the Ship of Theseus in that to exist in time is to be a sequence of
physical states where there is no inherent way to claim they form a
single “thing”; every moment in time the physical states in the world
update, and you are a re-instantiation of a thing with nearly
identical properties to the corresponding thing in the moment before
dependent type theory, where I think every term of a type is also a type in its own right.

What philosophical theory is this and who has developed this into deep conclusions, one way or the other?

In categorical data science, categories represent “schemas”, which are like entity-relationship diagrams, and an instance of a schema can be defined as a functor into the category of sets. I am interested in an argument from this point of view that an “instance” is a necessary concept for some reason, or otherwise maybe explaining how we might get rid of the use of that functor in that context if we reject the concept of an instance.

There is also a concept I think in categorical model theory where any functor from the theory category into another category counts as a “model” of the theory; so this would make me think that there is no structural difference between a functor between two theories versus a functor from a theory to a model.

Can't a class have no members?

The 1991 book "Parts of classes" by David Lewis is about set theory and mereology. Lewis says his "Main Thesis" is the following proposal: The parts of a class are all and only its subclasses. He goes on to conclude that singletons are atoms, i.e., in Lewis's set theory, he has identified the one-element class {x} with its sole member x. In this system, the answer to your question is yes: a thing is precisely a class with only one member.
For a fast but substantial description of Lewis's project, John Burgess wrote a nice review of "Parts of Classes" available from his website, here: https://www.princeton.edu/~jburgess/Lewis.pdf
About the mathematical consequences: Hamkins and Kikuchi wrote a nice paper about Lewis's system, here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06593 As I recall, Hamkins and Kikuchi show that Lewis's system is decidable, and consequently cannot serve as a foundational system for much of modern mathematics, in which many problems (e.g. the word problem in groups) are known to be undecidable.

In another way, the parts of a class are all and only its superclasses. For instance, the concept of a dog is made up from the concepts of having fur, being domesticated, having a wolf ancestor, and so on. Each of these concepts is a superclass of dog, and the intersection of all the superclasses is the concept of a dog.

@causative I would say that perhaps you are talking about the parts of a concept rather than the parts of a class. Evidently when you pass from concepts to classes by taking their extensions, the parthood relation gets reversed.

You ask:

Does this imply that we don’t need the concept of an “instance”? Can everything be defined as a collection of properties or relationships?

These are questions that are fundamentally ontological in nature and have to do with the classic problem of universals. For a very long time, it has been self-evident that there seem to be instances and classes in which we can lump instances together. Let's say you own two dogs: Casper and Wilfred. It is natural to consider Casper and Wilfred as individuals, but given their differences and similarities, attempt to create a word for what they have in common (dog). And a look around the world means there are all sorts of ways we can create categories (SEP). The two dogs are both male. The two dogs are different breeds. One dog is young and the other is old.
It's difficult to see how instances aren't necessary to thought, because it is from the instance that we derive the notion of identity. From a naturalized epistemology, it seems our minds are evolved to identify instances, in fact. The rest of the abstractions of classifications creates troubles. Should a breed be a concrete thing? What about a dog? What about an animal. These are the classic questions of how to deal with universals and particulars or which one can have a realist, conceptualist, or nominalist bent.
In fact, categories are so dominant in our ways of grouping together instances in life, there's a part of speech dedicated to assisting nouns in dealing with classes and subclasses: subsective modifier. From WP:

In linguistics, a subsective modifier is an expression which modifies another by delivering a subset of its denotation. For instance, the English adjective "skilled" is subsective since being a skilled surgeon entails being a surgeon. By contrast, the English adjective "alleged" is non-subsective since an "alleged spy" need not be an actual spy.

And categories that seem to exist independently and universally of people are called natural kinds (SEP). Forces, particles, organisms, and species are the sorts of things that seem to have structure independent of human thought. As far as their properties, when those properties have, well, the same property, then they are considered natural properties (SEP).
Are objects just bundles of properties? Hume thought so. He argued there was no substance that unified properties, and that there really wasn't anything to an object above and beyond its properties, and certainly no objects without properties. In fact, Hume's argument created a crisis of sorts because he argued there was nothing that unified the mind other than this bundle of perceptions of properties. From Britannica's article Bundle theory:

[The theory] advanced by David Hume to the effect that the mind is merely a bundle of perceptions without deeper unity or cohesion, related only by resemblance, succession, and causation. Hume’s well-argued denial of a substantial or unified self precipitated a philosophical crisis from which Immanuel Kant sought to rescue Western philosophy.

So, there is no canonical answer to your question, because you are asking after fundamental questions that present themselves to an ontologist. Where do we draw the line between classes and instances? How do we determine if something is real or a category of the mind? Do properties exist independently of objects? Each of these questions can absorb a thinker for years.

Got to bundle theory before I could :) (was considering writing my own answer).

@JuliusHamilton You can certainly elaborate. Your question was very broad, and certainly, Hume's thinking could use a better treatment than I have given it. :D

I think that if you look closely, anything you could call an "instance" is actually also a class having multiple instances. "Norwegian" is a good example because, would you believe it, there is North Norwegian which is distinct from South, West or East Norwegian, and each of these again can be divided into finer instances of Norwegian. Which reminds me of the old joke about "Northern Conservative Baptist Great Lakes Region Council of 1879, or Northern Conservative Baptist Great Lakes Region Council of 1912?".
Even individuals (or any other discernible objects) differ from place to place (family vs. work persona) and over time, and not only in the actual matter that makes them up: "You are not the man I married anymore"... So there are actually multiple instances of "me" scattered through time, probably an infinite number of them.
So yes: There are no instances. Everything we consider an "instance" is actually another collective, and we just decide to stop dissecting at some point because it is a good enough approximation, and to not get lost in infinities.

+1 I get the thrust of the point that even an instance of a dog can be viewed temporally as a series of instances of a dog at time t, but isn't the definition of an instance quite literally an example or approximation? Therefore, whether one consider an instance of dog Fido or a series of instances of dog Fido at time t, isn't one still bottoming out fundamentally in instances of some sort?

The following is an answer to your question from the viewpoint of Object-Oriented Programming, more general Object-Oriented Design and even more fundamental Object-Oriented Thinking, a type of ontology.
The main principle of object-orientation is to combine

properties,
methods,
and lifecycle

of objects to a class, if the objects are
similar in these respect.
Hence the strategy to avoid redundancy and its benefit is to form classes with more than one object. Singleton classes are not excluded, they have their use. Only the context and the intended goal can decide.
Ontologies are not discovered but constructed (= designed).

+1 Additionally, three OOP principles are encapsulation, polymorphism, and inheritance.

@JD Thanks for the edit and the upvote. Because of the downvotes from other participants I fear: The consequences of object-orientation for ontology building have not yet been fully recognized in the philosophical community.

Well, certainly computer modeling and applied ontologies are very important in understanding philosophy in an experimental light. You clearly have the vision to see it. ; )  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/experimental-philosophy/

Could be improved more information about object oriented thinking (Has it been advanced as a model of the real world by anybody in particular? Are people realists about it or just suggest it as a practical ontology? What does it mean to have a constructed ontology not a discovered one? (quine?)). And secondly, you could maybe be more explicit about how this resolves the question? (as I understand it, it's 'objects exist first, classes are things we construct around them, so objects aren't classes'?)

@Kaia I would be glad to expand a bit my view on the concept of classes and objects in the sense of general object-orientation. It’s more than can be said in a short comment. If you like, what about stating your comment as a separate post with some of your remarks converted into precise questions? (1/2)

@Kaia For short: IMO ontologies and the choice of classes and objects are not discovered in the real world like material objects in archeology or fossils in biology. Instead, they are theoretical concepts which serve as building blocks to develop well-structured theories. To put it blantly: An electron is an object from the class which the Dirac equation describes in precise form. (2/2)
